# How to call javascript in main window from iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

How to call javascript in main window from iframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.top.foo
```

for the top level window

```
window.parent.foo
```

for the direct parent

Answer (score 0):

```
window.parent.whatever
```