# calling js method in a document from iframe

Tags: javascript, html

How to call a js method thats defined in parent document from iframe?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function palert(){
    alert('h');
}
</script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Testing inner frame</h2>
        <iframe src="inner.html" width="100%" height="300">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to call palert() method from onclick event of a button thats inside inner.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call javascript in main window from iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370962/how-to-call-javascript-in-main-window-from-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try a simple

```
parent.palert();
```

?

like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function palert(){
    alert('h');
}
</script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Testing inner frame</h2>
       <iframe src="inner.html" width="100%" height="300">
          <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
          <a href="javascript:parent.palert();">click me</a>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by executing

```
parent.palert();
```