# Call main page function from iFrame?

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

Yes, I have seen this question, but I am still finding myself confused:
[How to Call JavaScript From Main Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370962/how-to-call-javascript-in-main-window-from-iframe)

I want to call a function that toggles an object with jQuery on the parent frame from an iframe. How exactly would something be done?

window.parent.[...?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main window:

```
function toggleMe() {
    $('#myid').toggle();
}
```

In child frame:

```
window.parent.toggleMe();
```